# Editing a shapefile uploaded using leaflet.shapefile

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, shapefile, leaflet.draw

I'm using Mapbox with Leaflet for drawing, editing and removing polygons etc. There might also be a case in which the user might have zipped shapefiles and want to use that directly, instead of drawing the polygons. So I'm using [leaflet.shapefile](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile) to upload shapefiles and add them to the map.

But when I try to edit the shapefiles using the Leaflet Draw control, I get an error telling me that "i.editing is undefined". I tried converting the layer to GeoJSON before adding it to the featureGroup just in case (like in the code below), to see if that had any effect, but it didn't.

```
var layergeojson = layer.toGeoJSON();
featureGroup.addLayer(layergeojson);
```

This is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqfeee81/11/) of what I have right now. I tried researching online to see any similar cases, but I'm not able to find any.

Is it possible to edit the uploaded shapefiles using the Leaflet Draw control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `var layergeojson = layer.toGeoJSON()`, the `layergeojson` now contains a plain GeoJSON object, not a Leaflet layer.

Therefore, `featureGroup.addLayer(layergeojson)` should throw an error (open your browser console). Instead, you should probably use the [`.addData()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-adddata) method: `featureGroup.addData(layergeojson)`.

As for editing your resulting layers, it might be related to this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203540/how-to-edit-an-existing-layer-using-leaflet/203773#203773

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I needed. This also seems to fix another issue I had with the previous setup, when I tried to convert the layer to a WKT string (not part of the jsfiddle). Thanks a lot!! :)

P.S: I didn't have to convert it to GeoJSON, since my main aim was to edit the shapefile, and converting it to GeoJSON was one of the different ways I tried to solve it. But that's a good little detail I can maybe use in the future. So thanks for that as well.